# Rand Dict value not working in python

Tags: python, dictionary, random

IS there any way for me to specify the VALUE of 'ben stiller' or 'bill murray that I want?

I know that I cant do random.choice(ben_stiller.values()):

I also changed the dict so the key is the name of the movie and works perfect now.

### ^

```
import random

last_man = {
    'Mark Walberg': '1',
    'Ben Stiller': '2',
    'Bill Murray': '3',

}

markymark = {
    'movie': 'The martian',
    'movie': 'The Departed',
    'movie': 'XYZ'
}

ben_stiller = {
    'movie': 'Meet the parents',
    'movie': 'Something about mary',
    'movie': 'dunno'
}

bill_murray = {
   'movie': 'Life Aquatic',
   'movie': 'rushmore',
   'movie': 'Groundhogs day'
}

print "There are three actors, one will be chosen randomly"
print "You have to name as many movies as they have been in"
print "If you get one wrong, you lose, you hae three chances, and must     get one correct"

random.choice(last_man.keys())

print "The actor randonly chosen is: ", random.choice(last_man.keys())

guesses_taken = 0

while guesses_taken <= 3:
    guess = raw_input(': ')
    guesses_taken = guesses_taken + 1

    if guess == random.choice(bill_murray.keys()):
        print "you won in %s guesses" % guesses_taken
        print guesses_taken
    elif guess == random.choice(ben_stiller.keys()):
        print "you won in %s guesses" % guesses_taken
        print guesses_taken
    elif guess == random.choice(markymark.keys()):
        print "you won in %s guesses" % guesses_taken
        print guesses_taken
    elif guess != random.choice(markymark.keys()):
        print "You lost"
        print guesses_taken
    else:
        print "you lose"
        exit(0)
```

Comment: You  might want to think again about how dictionaries work. Dictionaries can only have a single value per key. In the case of dictionary literals, last one wins, so e.g. `bill_murray` contains only `{'movie': "Groundhogs day"}`. In your case, `keys()` always returns `['movie']`.

Comment: You're missing the `:` at the end of your `if` statements

Comment: ... and : at the end of all of your elif statements.... FInd out about version control so you can spot the difference if you break your code.

Comment: Re: *'Can ignore this now'*. I'd delete the question if I were you. Especially as you've edited your code to correct the problem :)

Comment: I actually in the working version, had the key the name of the movie, and the value movie. Any way to do random.choice(bill_murray.values()): ? I  know that doesn't work, but how can i retrieve the value? I thought I could use the key to generate its value.

Comment: Iknow this isn't common use of a dict, but a dict most def can have keys with multiple values, using tuples nested inside the dict...or dict nested inside the dict.

Comment: As shown in my answer you can have multiple values, but not by setting a value at a time to the same key - use a `list`

Answer (score 0):

The full error syas

```
File "movie.py", line 42
  if guess == random.choice(bill_murray.keys())
                                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

So, the syntax is invalid. An `if` line needs to end with an `:`

If we sort out line 42 by adding the colon, we then get

```
File "movie.py", line 45
  elif guess == random.choice(ben_stiller.keys())
                                              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

So, the syntax is invalid. An `elif` line needs to end with an `:`

```
elif guess == random.choice(ben_stiller.keys()):
#                                              ^---- and so on
```

Syntax errors now gone.
Now we have another problem.
And a typo

> "you hae three chances, "

->

> "you have three chances, "

Anyway. if it presents me with

> The actor randonly chosen is:  Bill Murray

(Alright, two typos...)

and I choose "rushmore" it tells me I am wrong. As the comments have noted, when I try to add a value to an existing key ("movie") in a dictionary it gets replaced. Could we just have a list of movies?

Also, when I play this it isn't using the movies:

```
The actor randonly chosen is:  Bill Murray
: rushmore
You lost
1
: Groundhogs day
You lost
2
: Life Aquatic
You lost
3
: movie
you won in 4 guesses
4
```

Let's use lists of movies instead. As the value for the key of an actor's name.
And remove the `exit(0)`

Something like this:

```
import random

last_man = {
    'Mark Walberg': ['The martian', 'The Departed', 'XYZ'],
    'Ben Stiller': ['Meet the parents', 'Something about mary', 'dunno'],
    'Bill Murray': ['Life Aquatic', 'rushmore', 'Groundhogs day']

}


print "There are three actors, one will be chosen randomly"
print "You have to name as many movies as they have been in"
print "If you get one wrong, you lose, you have three chances, and must get one correct"

actor = random.choice(last_man.keys())
#^--- remember who

print "The actor randomly chosen is: ", actor

guesses_taken = 0

while guesses_taken <= 3:
    guess = raw_input(': ')
    guesses_taken = guesses_taken + 1

    if guess in last_man[actor]:
        print "you won in %s guesses" % guesses_taken
        print guesses_taken
        break
    else:
        print "you lose"
```

Comment: thanks a lot, I was THIS close to using the dict format you did with the actors and a nested list of the movies. I had just used that format for a diff dict set-up, similar but with states, their abbreviation, and population. As far as the typos- I knew they were there, was just seeing if the code worked. Initially I had it set up correctly, where it would give me a random actor, and three chances to guess one of his three movies and it worked perfect. I don't know what caused it to go wrong, something did. I wish I could pull up that version, I still see it in my terminal working correctly.

Comment: I know this is a strange way of using dict, but because I'm BRAND new to this, anything I am learning I tend to take to the max and use in unusual ways and see if I can figure out how to make it happen. In this case, I did figure it out, but then changed it to update the prints and somehow that screwed it all up. Is this a stupid way of learning python?

Comment: Trying things and seeing what happens is always good. But do learn about version control (e.g. git) so you can easily track what you change if things break.